# How to export a table on postgresql command line

Tags: postgresql

Anyone can do tell me how to do that?

(I know maybe is a dumb question but I'm trying to learn how to use command line of postgresql)

```
~$ psql mybase
psql (9.1.3)
Type "help" for help.
```

and then

```
mybase=# \dt



            List of relations
 Schema |        Name         | Type  |  Owner   
--------+---------------------+-------+----------
 public | xxxxxx              | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxx             | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxxxx         | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxx            | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxx           | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxx           | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxxxxx        | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxxx          | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxx           | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    | table | postgres
 public | xxxxxxxx            | table | postgres
```

only want one table to then do a restore =D thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create text files containing the data, use the [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command (or the `psql` command `\copy` which creates the output files on the client, rather than on the server as the `COPY` command does).

If you want to create SQL statements use [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: like pg_dump <mybase> -t <atable> -f testride.sql right?

Comment: @maniat1k: Right. If you have multiple tables of the same name, you would additionally provide the schema `-n <myschema>` to avoid confusion.